# Convert Date to correct format

Tags: powershell

I have CSV file with incorrect date format 19-08-22:01:00 (yy-MM-dd:HH:mm)

When I open it in excel it is not showing in date format. So I would like to convert this value using powershell.

I tried to change it using below command. But didnt work

```
$d = '19-08-22:01:00'
get-date $d
```

Could someone please help me to convert the date in correct format in which excel recognize it as date.

Comment: `19-08-22:01:00` isn't a typical `DateTime` to start with.  How is `$d` being populated?  Looks like it's custom formatted.

Answer (score 4):

I would use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.0):

```
$OldDate = '19-08-22:01:00'

# We need a provider so we pick the invariant one.
$Provider = [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

$OldDateFormat = 'yy-MM-dd:HH:mm'
# This format works well with Excel, assuming you use . and not , as a radix
$NewDateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'

$NewDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($OldDate, $OldDateFormat, $Provider)
$NewDate.ToString($NewDateFormat)
```

Comment: @mklement0 I don't follow your question. `yy` is not the same format string as `yyyy`. `TwoDigitYearMax` has a default value. I think it's either 2029 or 2059. Most dates with irregular time are all historical, so included setting that in case it's important. Obviously you can just look to see if the date is in the future or whatever and subtract a year, but this is a bit of how they built it to work.

Comment: It's `2029` for all cultures based on the Gregorian calendar (`[cultureinfo]::GetCultures('all') | Group-Object { $_.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax }, { $_.Calendar.GetType().Name }`). My question was why you think it's necessary to change the default in the context of answering this question. It sounds like you included it as _supplemental_ information - certainly worth knowing about - but since it isn't framed that way, readers may think it's a _necessary_ part of the solution, as I did, which can be confusing.

Comment: @mklement0 Every time I've worked with data that I've had to do century extrapolation on it's bitten me, so I always set it. It's probably just the data I'm working with (much of it is well over 30 years old) but it's my habit to always set it.

Comment: @mklement0 However, having just tested it, it doesn't seem like PowerShell pays attention to the value at all. It seems to ignore the provider. Although the equivalent code in C# works perfectly fine (or did when I used it two years ago), it doesn't seem to pay attention to it in PowerShell. I'm just going to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for checking. The fact that it works in C# but not in PowerShell is quite disconcerting, so I've reported the issue at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10438. You can work around the issue by using `[cultureinfo] ''` rather than `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` to obtain the invariant culture.

Comment: As it turns out, it is a .NET bug in `CultureInfo.Clone()`, which PowerShell just happens to surface consistently (in C# it only surfaces if you explicitly access the original culture's `.DateTimeFormat.Calendar` property before cloning): see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40953

Comment: @mklement0 Wow, what a bizarre bug. No wonder I remembered it working correctly!

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is fixing the format, you just need to replace that first colon with a space:

```
$d -replace '(?<=-\d{1,2}):', ' '
```

Comment: That is an improvement, but I don't think Excel recognizes the resulting format, at least not with the US-English culture in effect (not sure if there are any cultures where it would work; I suspect that there are culture-invariant formats that Excel recognizes).